# Unable to save "" connector configuration. Please try again

Tags: php, configuration, microsoft-teams, connector

I'm setting up microsoft teams connector app. I uploaded manifest.json successfully and connector app shows in apps area. But while configuring after getting webhook url it gives error Unable to save "" connector configuration. Please try again.

```
    var host = 'http://example.com';
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#webhookUrl').text('webhookUrl');
        // Initialize the Microsoft Teams Library
        microsoftTeams.initialize();
        microsoftTeams.settings.getSettings(function (settings) {
            var webhookUrl = settings.webhookUrl;
            $('#webhookUrl').text(webhookUrl);
        });

        // Set the 'Save' Button state
        microsoftTeams.settings.setValidityState(true);

        // Save handler when user clicked on Save button
        microsoftTeams.settings.registerOnSaveHandler(function (saveEvent) {
            microsoftTeams.getContext(function (context) {

                var url = host+'/external/msteam/connector';
                var entity = 'check-teams-'+context.teamId+'-'+context.channelId;
                microsoftTeams.settings.setSettings({
                    entityId: entity,
                    contentUrl: url,
                    configName: 'Check Teams Connector'
                });
            });

            microsoftTeams.settings.getSettings(function (settings) {
                var webhookUrl2 = settings.webhookUrl;
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    url: 'example.com/save/data',
                    data: {'webhook': webhookUrl2, 'check': 1, 'notify': 1},
                    success: function (data, status) {
                        saveEvent.notifySuccess();
                        $('#debug').text('success');
                    },
                    error: function () {
                        $('#debug').text('error');
                        saveEvent.notifyFailure('error');
                    }
                });
            });
        });

        microsoftTeams.settings.registerOnRemoveHandler(function (removeEvent) {
            var removeCalled = true;
            removeEvent.notifySuccess();
        });
    });
```

Comment: should the registerOnSaveHandler() encapsulate the getSettings()?

Comment: Are you calling microsoftTeams.settings.setSettings(); in your connector configuration page?

Comment: @Trinetra-MSFT yes calling in getContext function.

Comment: Could you please confirm if you have added contentUrl in ValidDomains of your Connector in [Connector Portal](https://outlook.office.com/connectors/publish)?

Comment: @Wajeed-MSFT yes it is added already.

Comment: It's working finally i changed http with https. And also used try catch on functions